Не поддерживается Xamarin в Visual Studio. Ошибка при создание проекта (не удалось найти указанный файл)
При попытке установить фреймворк Xamarin в VS не смог найти его в редакторе установок различных инструментов, поэтому перешел в Отдельные компоненты и там нашел Xamarin. Только там в скобках написано (не поддерживается), но я все ровно установил и при попытке создать проект у меня появилась ошибка:

Нашел в инете что Microsoft прекратила поддержку Xamarin. Если это так, то на C# больше нет фреймворков для создание ПО под мобилку? Или все таки можно исправить ошибку и начать учиться делать ПО?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76652602

MAUI же есть...

@aepot понял, спасибо!
